# IIS multiple request limit for stress tests

Tags: c#, iis, asynchronous, request, stress-testing

I want to create a c# application to send multiple requests to my server. So I will get pieces of information about the server's performance. But I wonder if there is a limit for incoming requests from the same origin within a certain time frame. Is IIS limiting repeated requests **by default**? If true, how can I disable this for my requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limit by yourself in the `applicationHost.config` like this:-

```
<limits maxBandwidth="65536" maxConnections="1024" connectionTimeout="00:01:00" />
```

You can also check out [Request Filtering in IIS](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering)

Comment: is IIS limiting as default the multiple requests?

Comment: Yes..In IIS7 you can filter out.

Comment: @youtubeline:- The limitations by default are the capacity of your server to serve those requests.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default IIS doesn't filter or limit anything. One of the best things about IIS, IMO - it performs well right out of the box for static content.